# using php to pull a value from an array

Tags: php, paypal

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array (
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2012-01-04T21:36:32Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 4564e64d7f75f
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 51.0
    [BUILD] => 2278658
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10764
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed at this time. Please try again later.
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed at this time. Please try again later.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [L_ERRORPARAMID0] => ProcessorResponse
    [L_ERRORPARAMVALUE0] => PPAV
    [AMT] => 25.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [AVSCODE] => N
    [CVV2MATCH] => M
)
```

If i wanted to echo out the value for [L_LONGMESSAGE0] (which is 'This transaction cannot be processed at this time. Please try again later'), how would I do this using php?

To be even more clear, i am getting this array from PayPal when i use this command:
urldecode(print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true))

So, given that that command produces the array shown above, how would I echo out [L_LONGMESSAGE0]?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumption:** This array is inside an `$arr` variable.

```
echo $arr['L_LONGMESSAGE0'];
```

Comment: i just revised the question to be more clear--unfortunately the suggested responses aren't working.  When i put the array inside $arr, i get 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\site.com\test.html on line 3'

Comment: Come on man, you didn't literally try to put the code you just posted into a variable did you? What you posted is the way arrays are visually represented in PHP. It's by no means _actual_ PHP syntax. Learn more about building an array [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp), and/or [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/arrays.php). It's pretty easy stuff, you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: i'm pretty familiar with how to build an array, the problem is that this is what PayPal gives back to me when i have this in the code:  urldecode(print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true)).  All i want to do is pull L_LONGMESSAGE0 out of $httpParsedResponseAr.  does that make sense?  would it be echo $httpParsedResponseAr['L_LONGMESSAGE0'];

Comment: that worked, i guess i answered my own question.  thanks for leading me to it

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $myarray["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your array is stored in the variable $response, you would do

```
echo $response["L_LONGMESSAGE0"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat off-topic, but I hope you're not going to present that information to a buyer?
API error responses are meant to be interpreted by you, the merchant, with a friendlier message shown to the buyer.
At minimum, you can do a simple switch;

```
switch ($httpParsedResponseAr['L_ERRORCODE0']) {
        case "10764":
            echo "Unable to process your transaction. Please try a different payment method.";
            break;
        case "10002":
            echo "Unexpected error. Please try again in an hour.";
            // Log error
            error_log("10002 error in site",1,"operator@example.com");
            break;
        case "10001":
            echo "Unexpected error from PayPal. Our engineers have been notified.";
            error_log("10001 in site",1,"operator@example.com");
            break;
    }
```